# Hibernate keeps asking for hibernate_sequence when trying to persist DTO with generated UUID

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, uuid, dropwizard

I'm using dropwizard-hibernate and postgres  (hibernate version 5.3.7)

For my DTO i have a base DTO that contains an ID fields (all DTOS extend this class)

In the database schema the Id look like this

```
id uuid default gen_random_uuid() not null
```

My configuration for the ID is like this:

```
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private UUID id;
```

In theory this should work but every time that i try to persist an entity i get an error saying

```
ERROR: relation \"hibernate_sequence\" does not exist\
```

I've tried everything and nothing works.. i tried just with @Id and @GeneratedValue  (according to the latest hibernate documentation that should be enough for the UUID config) and many other combination of annotations but every time I try to persist the entity i get the missing sequence issue.

I know I could "fix it" just adding the hibernate_sequence table in the database but I shouldn't need it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this & it's worked as expected:

```
@Column(name = "uid")
@Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
@Type(type = "pg-uuid")
private UUID uid;
```

I realize that `@Generated` is a legacy annotation, but it seems to work.